# How to replace the properties of the fragment

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Can I replace the property of the elementin in itext? That is, not just replace String like this
:

https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-replacing-pdf-objects

I need to replace the properties of the fragment. For example, you find a word and apply it to .setFontSize(), etc.

*I know that there is such a function in **aspos**, but it does not suit me, because there you need to buy a license to remove the watermark at the top of the document*

Comment: _"I know that there is such a function in Aspose, but it does not suit me, because there you need to buy a license to remove the watermark at the top of the document"_ --> You need to buy a license to get "AGPL" out of the document properties of a PDF made with iText. You need to buy a license if you distribute your software without giving your source code away.

Comment: What do you have in mind?You can get more information